# onSpecialEdit() for Google App Script on a sheet with many users executes for all, each time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This can't be right.  What am I missing?

I have a Google Sheet with scripts.  The scripts are using certain ui functions that require authentication and special permissions coming from an onEdit() event.  Therefore, I had to create onSpecialEdit() and the custom trigger to run that function with event source of the spreadsheet and event type onEdit().  This all works fine. Script does what it should.

From what I've seen, each person who needs to have this ability and access the special edit will need their own trigger.  That is created for them automatically. Triggers all work for each person.

Now, what I see is that when I do an action that triggers onEdit(), it appears to run the onSpecialEdit() 20 times...once for each person who has that trigger....I'm assuming.

This can't be right. What am I missing? Is there another way to create triggers where they are only executed by the person triggering?  Is this approach wrong?

Comment: First, things you did wrong is creating simple trigger for many user for one project, which doesn't make sense because trigger work by project it's attached to, not by user. So if you'd 20 triggers which is the limit too for single script, every time user edit something its obvious that function will run 20 times, you just need one `onEdit`.

Comment: Can you clarify which actions that require authorization are used by the trigger? Why is it necessary that these run on behalf of the user who edited the spreadsheet?

Comment: Triggers that use a alert UI with response and email notifications sent by user.  These are requirements and it functions fine, with the exception that each trigger must be used.  Seems like if the authorization is by a single user for the trigger that only their trigger should run.  A little confusing that everyone's triggers also run, but are not authorized by them.  Is there a way to make the trigger private and not available except to the user who authorized it?

Comment: The triggers run under the authorization of the user who created the trigger, but any user who edits the spreadsheet will fire that trigger. With that said, consider editing your question to provide the relevant parts of your code in order to clarify what exact methods your function is using and, hopefully, find an appropriate workaround.

Comment: Thanks.  I have lots, and lots of code...and many different aspects that use the special permissions coming from onEdit() which forces me to use triggers in order to get that special permission.  I really don't feel that adding code has anything to do with the trigger problem.  I would have to not meet the requirements of the program in order to "find an appropriate workaround."  I understand that we all love to see code and find problems and solution to code, but this question is about how Google treats the permissions and triggers.

Comment: vector, how you would go about allowing different people to make onEdit() triggered events show UI response or send emails as a result of the action?  From what I've experienced and read, these must be special triggers that are called with special permissions.  The only way the code will execute is by creating a trigger to run a onSpecialEdit() function.  Google throws an error when onEdit() tries to do the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

- You want to have an `onEdit` trigger that has access to services that require authorization.
- These services should have access private of the user who has caused the trigger to run by editing the spreadsheet.
- Since the services require authorization, it cannot be a simple but an installed trigger ([Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)).
- Since installed triggers act on behalf of the user who installed them, they can only access data of the user who installed them.
- Therefore, each user whose data should be accessed needs to install the trigger, so multiple triggers should be installed.
- A trigger runs whenever **any** user edits the spreadsheet, it doesn't have to be the user who installed the trigger. Because of this, all of the installed `onEdit` triggers will run whenever any user edits the spreadsheet.

#### Solution:

Use [Session.getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser) and [Session.getEffectiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser) to check whether the user editing the spreadsheet (`getActiveUser`) is the same as the one who installed the spreadsheet (`getEffectiveUser`). If it's not, stop the function execution. This way, only one of the multiple `onEdit` triggers will make the corresponding actions.

#### Code sample:

```
function onEditTrigger(e) {
  const active = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  const effective = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  if (active === effective) {
    // TRIGGER ACTIONS
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was imagining there was something like this.  I already have the OAuth scopes for the userinfo in the project scope, but it throws an error for EffectiveUser.  Not sure if I have to reauth or why ActiveUser works and the EffectiveUser is an error.  Ideas?

Comment: @GregGriffin You have `userinfo.email` scope added? What error are you getting?

Comment: Yes, I have the scope added, which is why "ActiveUser" works and gives results, but the very next line is EffectiveUser and it throw an error that I do not have permissions?  Is it possible that you can only get EffectiveUser for your own and this should be a try/catch?  "Exception: You do not have permission to call Session.getEffectiveUser. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"

Comment: @GregGriffin That doesn't make sense for me, and I can definitely use `getEffectiveUser` for other users without errors. If you don't set [explicit scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes), do you get the same behavior? Also, what happens when you add `try...catch`?

Comment: I've tried the same code and auth on several different programs and get the same issue with each.  They are all inside Google Workspace accounts (and different ones).  Will try to see how and when this happens or what is causing it.

Comment: Hi @GregGriffin, if you don't set the scopes explicitly, do you get the same behavior?

Comment: The problem with effectiveuser and email checking is that it is SLOOOOOWWWW!!!  The script needs to run for each person just to see if it should continue after the check.  Adds a HUGE amount of overall execution time.  Would be great if there was a way to specify the scope prior to even running.  This issue appear whether or not it is explicit.